# how to read out variables from a opegles shader?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, fragment-shader, glsles

I am writing a particle filter application for Android. I want all the particles to be processed in parallel by the GPU.

I have the code in the vertex shader to update the position of each particle or vertex based on its current position, but I can't figure out how to write the updated location back out to openGLES, or even make it available to the shader processing the same vertex on the next run.

Attribute variables have the appropriate scope but are read only within the vertex shader.

Uniform variables have the appropriate scope, but you can't do arrays (so it would be hard to implement uniforms for a large number of vertices). And again they are read only within the vertex shader.

Varying variables have a scope that allows modification but they are only visible to the fragment shader within the program. Which could work if the fragment shader could write information out to openGLES. Can Fragment shaders modify attibute variables (for the next run)?

Is there a way for the Fragment shaders to update any variable? {attribute, uniform, varying, default, other} or maybe write out a buffer not to the display but to memory?

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking about shaders in completely the wrong way. They take input (e.g. in attributes, uniforms, sampled textures) do some calculations and then output them for the next stage of the render pipeline.

You cannot write to a uniform, because it would not make any sense. Hundreds or thousands of instances of your shader run simultaneously and each one uses the same set of uniforms.

That said, what you *can* do is write to a texture attachment if you use FBOs. If you do it intelligently, you can then lookup values in this texture in your vertex shader to determine the new position for your particle. You will have to come up with a scheme for addressing which texel corresponds to which particle, how to pack the properties into a 3 or 4 channel texel, etc. But this is how GPU-based particle systems were often implemented pre-Compute Shaders.

Alternatively, you could use transform feedback. But I am not sure if OpenGL ES supports this?

I should point out that when doing it this way, all of the computation for particle position, color, etc... is deferred to a special fragment shader pass. Your particle vertex shader basically amounts to little more than a texture lookup using the results of the earlier fragment shader pass (in order to establish the position, color, etc. that the vertex should use). There are tutorials and tech demos related to this if you look on Google. In any case, this is really the only way you're going to be able to do this 100% on the GPU on embedded hardware, since you do not have compute shaders or transform feedback.

Comment: OpenGL ES 3.0 supports transform feedback, unfortunately I am still back on 2.0. Your suggestion sounds like it might work, but a link to an example would help. I'll see what I can find now that I know what to look for.